# what does the eporch means in tf,string_input_producer function

Tags: tensorflow

There is api function in tensorflow,string_input_producer function,
tf.train.string_input_producer(string_tensor, num_epochs=None, shuffle=True, seed=None, capacity=32, name=None)
what does eporchs means here?Is it the same meaning as tranning in eporch?

Comment: When I use filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(["train.csv"],1)  it will report error like that ,tensorflow.python.framework.errors.OutOfRangeError: FIFOQueue '_0_input_producer' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 1, current size 0)

Comment: "epoch" means how many times it'll produce each example. `epoch=2` means it'll produce each string twice

Answer (score 0):

epochs means the number of iteration over train data to learn it better.

and considering to your error it's not related to this input. it's about your file. maybe it cant find the proper file to read.

edit after seeing your code:

you never initialized your variables. initialize them with sess.initialize_all_variables()

Answer (score 0):

See https://github.com/davidsandberg/facenet/issues/69 , you have to unexpectedly call:

```
tf.initialize_local_variables().run()
```

... then it will work...